# No DEP Profiles or MDM Processes running but still getting DEP notifications?

Tags: macbook-pro, notifications, monterey, mdm, automated-device-enrollment

New to the site and have a question about a 2017 MacBook (12inch Intel Core M3) I recently picked up from a pawn shop.

It’s running macOS Monterey and I was able to go through the setup, add my iCloud and sign in and everything and yet I keep getting DEP notifications from Northwestern University. I even wiped it when I first got it yet I still get this.

If I click “Details” on the notification it will take me to the Profiles screen (This is the only way to find it as going to Apple Icon > Preferences and searching for the profiles button reveals nothing, it’s not there)

On the profiles screen there are no profiles, I’m afraid to click allow for Northwestern University to setup my laptop so I always click cancel and it will let me stay in the profiles pane but there’s never anything there.

Searching through my Activity Monitor also shows that there are no MDM processes running.

Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: You'll have to contact NWU's IT department and get them to take that system out of their MDM. One of the purposes of MDM enrollment is to prevent exactly what you are trying to do... So let's hope that whoever sold that Mac to the pawn shop was the legal owner of the laptop.

Comment: Steve Chambers - thanks for the advice I will definitely look into contacting them, I haven’t bought a Mac since 2012 so I thought if it was clear of iCloud than it was good, wasn’t even aware DEP existed until getting this one.